# Ansible pull from svn

Tags: svn, ansible

I am trying the pull model with Ansible, in particular I need to checkout ansible playbooks from SVN.
I tried

```
ansible-pull  -d “<destination directory ie. /home/me/playbooks>”  -U “http://myversioncontrol.com/myrepo” -m subversion
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR! Unsuported repo module subversion, choices are git
```

Yes, with the spelling error (Unsuported).
If I execute the command `ansible-doc -l` I can see subversion in the list of the modules.
I also installed python-subversion (apt-get install python-subversion) and checked that is correctly installed. 
 
However, I still have that error, how can I make ansible-pull to work with svn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-m` parameter for `ansible-pull` is not a standard ansible module (that you get by `ansible-doc -l`).
It is an internal wrapper around standard module inside `ansible-pull` cli utility.
As per time of writing this answer, `git` is the only supported pull-module (and the default one).
[Here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/cli/pull.py#L54) is the definition: `SUPPORTED_REPO_MODULES = ['git']`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I needed to edit the installed pull.py file here (Centos 7):

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/pull.py
```

I added subversion like this:

```
SUPPORTED_REPO_MODULES = ['git', 'subversion']
```

The command line I ran was like this:

```
ansible-pull -m subversion -U http://subversion.company.com/test/ansible/trunk/playbook --full local.yml -i hosts
```

Without --full I get an error saying:

```
E155000: '/home/user/.ansible/pull/computername' already exists
```

Without -i hosts it gives an error:

```
sudo: a password is required
```

Seemingly because it is using an implicit localhost

```
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html
```

My hosts file has an entry:

```
[pull]
localhost connection=paramiko ansible_user=ansible
```

If you don't specify local.yml it will match the hostname, which will then expect computername.yml to exist. Which may be fine.